# PHP code error / get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling with below code & I keep getting this error on WordPress - can't find my way around it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

```
public function __construct( $id ) {
    $this->id    = $id;
    $this->post  = get_object_vars( get_post( $id ) );
    $this->date  = $this->get_date();
    $this->set_gallery_folder();
}
```

Comment: Well, the error message says that the thing you passed to `get_object_vars` is null. That comes from `get_post($id)`, so I guess you need to think about why that might return `null`.

Comment: `get_post($id)` cannot find a post with the referenced ID so either $id is empty, or there is no post in the database for the given $id